# Properly switch Caps Lock and Esc

Tags: linux, keyboard, xorg, kde

I'm on KDE Neon 5.27 with X11, and the settings app has an option "Swap Esc and Caps Lock". I've been using this for a while, but some applications still think they're not swapped. I have to press the physical escape key to use escape for some applications, which then also enables caps lock. It's mostly games that do the wrong keys, like Minecraft for example. It also happened with VSCode until I changed a setting.

I've been putting up with this for a while, but I've recently downloaded PICO-8 and it happens in that as well, and is much harder to deal with, I have to press escape, alt-tab out, disable caps lock, and alt-tab back in every time I want to switch between the code editor and the terminal. So now I really need a fix.

Is there a way to actually switch the keys, as in only send the escape key to the application when I press caps lock, instead of relying on the application to use the correct mapping?